# How to read child view's State property from parent view and have the parent view update when the property changes in the child view - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, view, swiftui, state

I'm trying to make my parent view update when one of the properties of its children changes.
I have tried to use a `Binding` but the value never updated in the parent view - it only updated in the child view.

This is some sample code that simplifies the problem I have:

```
struct ArrayDisplayWithPageNumber: View {
    var arrayDisplay: ArrayDisplay
    @Binding var index: Int  // This should update when 'index' changes in 'arrayDisplay'.

    init() {
        self.arrayDisplay = ArrayDisplay()
        self._index = self.arrayDisplay.$index
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            arrayDisplay
                .padding()
            Text("Page number: \(index + 1)")  // Stays at "Page number: 1".
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ArrayDisplay: View {
    var greetings: [String] = ["Hello", "Hola", "Bonjour"]
    @State var index: Int = 0  // This is the property I want to read in the parent view.

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Next greeting") {
                if self.index + 1 == self.greetings.count {
                    self.index = 0  // Simple check to prevent array out of bounds error.
                } else {
                    self.index += 1  // Increments index if it's not at it's highest index value.
                }
            }
            Text(greetings[index])
                .font(.title)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to merge both the View's I've created so is there any way to read the `index` property in `ArrayDisplay` and have `ArrayDisplayWithPageNumber` update when it changes?

If you can provide some code that solves my problem and explain why my code didn't work it'll be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance!